# I am having trouble with my postgresql query

Tags: postgresql

I have a query in mysql works well, but when I go to postgresql does not update me, I want to know where is my error.

I leave my php file the query *update* does not work

```
<?php
 require_once "Controllers/conexion.php";
 session_start();

    $resultado=pg_query("SELECT nextval('user_id_seq') as key");
    $row=pg_fetch_array($resultado, 0);
    $key=$row['key'];
  try {
$resultado = pg_query($conexion,"select * from encuesta_respuesta where id_user = '".$_SESSION['user']."' and id_encuesta = '".$_POST['id_encuesta']."'");


while( $row = pg_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
    $data = $row;
} 


if ($data['estado']=='F') {
    header("Location: Inicio.php");
}



foreach($_POST['pregunta'] as $id_pregunta=>$valor){
    $query="insert into encuesta_respuesta_opcion values (".$key.",".$_POST['id_encuesta'].",".$id_pregunta.",".$valor.")";
    $resultado = pg_query($conexion,$query);
}


$query="update encuesta_respuesta set estado='F' where id_user=".$_SESSION['user']." and id_encuesta = ".$_POST['id_encuesta']; 
$resultado = pg_query($conexion,$query);    

$resp['error']=false;
 } catch (Exception $e) {
$resp['error']=true;
 }

 header("Location: Inicio.php");
 ?>
```

Comment: Is there any error you got? And also can you please post your table schema?

Comment: You shouldn't be concatenating (user supplied) values into a SQL string. Your application is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Answer (score 0):

Directly try to `update` data in your database, check this query works or not. If it works, then you have to change your query building procedure in your application. For example:

```
 postgres=# create table test (id_user VARCHAR (50) PRIMARY KEY, id_encuesta VARCHAR (50), estado VARCHAR (10));
 postgres=# insert into test values ('anower','engg.','A');
 postgres=# update test set estado='F' where id_user='anower' and id_encuesta='engg.';
```

Answer (score 0):

The query should work the same in MySql and postgres.

If you are getting different results during updates then your survey tables arent the same.

Most liked `id_user` and `id_encuesta` are autoincrement fields. So they dont necesary have the same values.

Try using a Select to see if they have same survey information.

```
 SELECT *
 FROM survey 
 where id_user=".$_SESSION['user']." 
   and id_encuesta = ".$_POST['id_encuesta'];
```